# map as props in DrawFToolbar does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

i tried to simplified my codes to get sooner a solution, I have a Map component and a DrawFToolbar component, I send map as props to DrawFToolbar component, there are some console lines in DrawFToolbar  to check.so in console I get this messages: "DrawFToolbar rendered" and "DrawFToolbar useEffect hook triggered" and then map send to console, it seems to be a valid map element () but when compiler reach to run any method of map , i get this error:  "map.addLayer is not a function" . for example i want to add a marker to map and get mentioned error. following i put my codes it make easy solving this error :

```
import L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import 'leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw.css';
import 'leaflet-toolbar/dist/leaflet.toolbar.css';
import 'leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw.js';
import 'leaflet-toolbar/dist/leaflet.toolbar.js';
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import Axios from "axios";
import  DrawFToolbar from './DrawFToolbar';
import 'leaflet-toolbar';

 
function Map() {
  const mapRef = useRef(null);  
  const [drawToolbarLoaded, setDrawToolbarLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {

    if (mapRef.current) {
    const map = L.map(mapRef.current).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
      maxZoom: 18,
    }).addTo(map);
  

    setDrawToolbarLoaded(true);
  
   return () => {
      map.remove();
    }
  }
  
  }, []);

  
  return (<div ref={mapRef} style={{ height: '400px' }} > 
            {drawToolbarLoaded && <DrawFToolbar mapRef={mapRef} />}
          </div>);
  
}

export default Map
```

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw.css';
import 'leaflet-toolbar/dist/leaflet.toolbar.css';
import 'leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw.js';
import 'leaflet-toolbar/dist/leaflet.toolbar.js';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';


function DrawFToolbar(props) {

  console.log('DrawFToolbar rendered');
  useEffect(() => {
     
    console.log('DrawFToolbar useEffect hook triggered');
    const map = props.mapRef.current;
    
    console.log(map)
      if (map) {
      L.marker([51.6, -0.09]).addTo(map);
    }
  
  }, [props.mapRef]);

  return null;
   
}

export default DrawFToolbar;
```

I expect to know why leaflet map's methods in DrawFToolbar do not work whereas map exist and apparently is a valid leaflet map. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `map` needed for `.addTo(map)` is NOT the map container DOM Element (stored here in `mapRef`), but the JS object returned by Leaflet [`L.map()`](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-l-map) factory:

```js
const map = L.map(mapRef.current)
//    ^-- This object
```

(The same that you use for `map.remove()`)

So in your case you could simply store that object in another React ref, to provide it to your `<DrawFToolbar>` Component:

```
function Map() {
  /** ref for the DOM Element */
  const mapContainerRef = useRef(null);
  /** ref for the Leaflet JS object */
  const mapObjectRef = useRef();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (mapContainerRef.current) {
      const map = L.map(mapContainerRef.current);
      // Store it in its own ref
      mapObjectRef.current = map;
  
      return () => {
        map.remove();
      };
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={mapContainerRef}> 
      <DrawFToolbar mapRef={mapObjectRef} />
    </div>
  );
}
```